# What exactly did Emily pick after rejecting from cheerleader team?

Tags: dialogue, brick

In Brick (2005), Brendan asks Brain for the whereabouts of Emily:

> Brain: Well, I know she's been poking in with the Ivy-bound 
>   cheerleading elite, Laura Dannon's crowd.
>
> Brendan: Laura Dannon there on the Linc'?
>
> Brain: And Brad Bramish. Cream on the upper-crust. Anyway, Em tagged
>   after them for a bit, but it didn't work out. **She picked her way down
>   the food chain.**

Here Brendan says Emily teaming with Laura Dannon didn't work out, so 
what she picked in way down the food chain?

I know "[way down the food chain](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+the+bottom+of+the+food+chain)" is simply an English Idiom,
but still what exactly does she pick here in form of food chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the next line:

> Last I seen she was with whasshername, that drama vampire. Small time dealer, the evil one, the one you dated

They are saying that Emily, having failed to get in with the high crowd, moved down the list to the next most popular, then less more popular, and least popular. She was looking to get in with someone popular/powerful but had to keep going down the list since it didn't work.

Comment: I've received some feedback that using code-blocks (backticks) for quotes is confusing to screen-readers (which read out letter by letter), as well as being semantically incorrect as it renders as <code> rather than <quote> or <blockquote> tags.  Is there any harm in allowing the edit that changed this?